# create vertical space php

Tags: php, wordpress, hook-woocommerce

hey so I have this code trying to generate QR code

```
        <div class="pd_order_barcode_div" style="text-align: right; margin: 40px; ">
         
                 <img class="pd_order_barcode" style="margin-top: -40; margin-right: 10;   " src="https://2tfh7u96zl.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/added-jest-tests/barcode?type=<?php echo $barcodetype.'&value='.(($barcodetype == 'qrcode') ? $checkinpath .'Tax No:302188012300003'.'/'.' vat:'.$order->get_total_tax().'/'.'discount amt:'.$order->get_discount_total(): $order).'&includeText='.(get_option('plugindistrict_orderbarcodes_showtextupc') == 1 ? 'true' : 'false'); ?>" />
```

and the result is showing in the scanner like this
302188012300003/total_tax/discount_total
how can I make it show like

1. 302188012300003
2. total_tax
3. discount_total

Comment: Try to replace `'/'` by the percent-encoded value for a new line: `'%0A'` (ASCII 10 - line feed). It could also be: `'%0D'` (ASCII 13 - carriage return) or a combination: `'%0D%0A'`. The problem is that I don't use aws, so I don't know. You have to add the numbering manually as well.

Comment: That's actually Work thanx you so much  ( the '%0A' )

Answer (score 0):

Assume that scanner result is set in the `$string` variable,you can use this way:

```
$string = '302188012300003/total_tax/discount_total';

$replacedString = explode('/', $string);

foreach ($replacedString as $index => $str) {
    echo ($index + 1) . ' ' . $str;
}
```